# How do I change the ZIndex of the Thumb on a Slider

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So I have this style for my Slider and for some reason, the thumb is under the bar as shown here:

[image]

And I want it to be on top of the bar - in front of it and not behind it.
What causes this behaviour and what's the proper way of dealing with this?

I've tried setting the `ZIndex` by doing `Panel.ZIndex` and setting it to a higher value such as 10 but that didn't seem to change anything.

```
<Style x:Key="SliderRepeatButton" TargetType="RepeatButton">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                <Border BorderBrush="#E6E6E6" Background="#EAF8E6" Height="8" Margin="-5,0,0,0"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="SliderRepeatButton1" TargetType="RepeatButton">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="Green" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="YellowGreen" Height="3"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="SliderThumb" TargetType="Thumb" >
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Ellipse Height="15" Width="15" Fill="Orange"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="Slider"  TargetType="Slider">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Track Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_Track">
            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton1}"  Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge"/>
            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb Style="{StaticResource SliderThumb}" Panel.ZIndex="20"/>
            </Track.Thumb>
            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton}" Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge"/>
            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        </Track>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="Horizontal_Slider" TargetType="Slider">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="21" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="104" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Slider}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but I guess you should change the sequence in XAML:

```
<Track Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_Track">
        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton1}" Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge"/>
        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>           
        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButton}" Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge"/>
        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        <Track.Thumb>
            <Thumb Style="{StaticResource SliderThumb}" Panel.ZIndex="20"/>
        </Track.Thumb>
    </Track>
```

The last element in a Panel gets the hightest ZIndex, afaics.
Assuming "Track" is a Panel or adds its children to its ItemsPanel...

Comment: Oh my.. I thought it had to be on the top and not on the bottom.. Thank you!

Comment: Yes agree, it's not intuitive. Also that setting ZIndex is not reliable is perplexing. The actual value is evaluated in arrange path(?).
Had spent some hours once to find out why the header in a GroupRowStyle sometime seemed to vanish, So I remember this one.. ;)

Comment: @VALine, [how to say thank you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269683/1997232) on StackOverflow.